# Clash between textpos and pmboxdraw

Tags: textpos

I'd like to include icons from the package `pmboxdraw` into a beamer slide.

However, this package defines a square icon `\textpos` which is re-defined by textpos.
I can't use another square because I'm using it to have an increasing gradation like this : ▁ ▄ ▆.

What can I do to avoid this package clash ?

Here is a problematic MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \pmboxdrawuni{2582}
        \pmboxdrawuni{2585}
        \textblock
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The thrown error is : `Command \textblock already defined. \pmbd@UniDef\textblock{2588}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a naming conflict. My suggestion is to do

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\let\textblockpm\textblock
\let\textblock\relax

\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \pmboxdrawuni{2582}
        \pmboxdrawuni{2585}
        \textblockpm
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can also just do `\let\textblock\relax` and use `\pmboxdrawuni{2588}` instead of `\textblock`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the options with `\pmboxdrawuni{2588}`, I'm using it.